# Passing overloaded pointer to member function signal as an argument to QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, c++14

In Qt if the signal is not overloaded it can be passed to the connect method like this.

```
QObject::connect(comboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, [&]()-> void {});
```

But if the signal is overloaded then it can be done in two steps.

## Example:

In Qt's QComboBox class the highlighted method is overloaded

```
void QComboBox::highlighted(int index)
void QComboBox::highlighted(const QString & text)
```

When using the QObject::connect we can declare the pointer to member function variable and then use it which requires 2 steps.

```
       void (QComboBox::*fptr) (int) = &QComboBox::highlighted;
            QObject::connect(comboBox, fptr, [&]()-> void {
                                 insertWidgetToMapAndSend(listView);
                             });
```

Is it possible to pass the overloaded method without the declaration of **ftptr** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast inline:

```
QObject::connect(comboBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::highlighted), [&]()-> void {
                             insertWidgetToMapAndSend(listView);
                         });
```

But starting with Qt 5.7, use [`qOverload`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload):

```
QObject::connect(comboBox, qOverload<int>(&QComboBox::highlighted), [&]()-> void {
                             insertWidgetToMapAndSend(listView);
                         });
```

or `QOverload` in pre C++14:

```
QObject::connect(comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::highlighted), [&]()-> void {
                             insertWidgetToMapAndSend(listView);
                         });
```

Comment: That's the proper way to do it, and indeed `qOverload` and `QOverload` are preferred over the `static_cast`: they are less verbose.